# SQLite with JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a pretty simple query that works just fine as is. But I need to add some fields from another table that has a match in one of the resulting fields. Here's the query that works:

```
select *
from "Time Track"
where Username = "JustMe"
and WeekNum = "1"
```

"Recnum" is the linking field between "Time Track" and "Pro Track". From the "Pro Track" table I need to pull two fields called "TKNum" and "Type". Anyone feel like helping me out?

Comment: is this a sqlite question or dont you know how to do basicaly in sql?

Comment: lol, silent donvoters day ...

Comment: Thank you for that halfbit. You are correct, I do not have much experience with joins in SQL. Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: so I suggest, to put your eyes into "SQL JOIN" documentation. Its much more efficient, than writing it down here. Call again, if you still ned help ...

Comment: Tried that. Using a Cross Join but ended up getting all records in the Pro Track table instead of just the records that resulted from the query above.

Scratch that ... I missed one "and" clause. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select "Time Track".*, "Pro Track"."TKNum", "Pro Track"."Type"
from "Time Track" JOIN "Pro Track" ON "Time Track"."Recnum" = "Pro Track"."Recnum"
where Username = "JustMe"
and WeekNum = "1"
```

BTW, it's **columns**, not fields...

You can also add the keyword LEFT to you JOIN, i.e from "Time Track" **LEFT JOIN** "Pro Track" ON, will also return rows from TimeTrack without any matching ProTrack rows.